# The Kirby diagram of a manifold glued along the lens space $L(p,1)$

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, 3-manifolds, 4-manifolds, kirby-calculus

Suppose $K$ is a knot in $S^3$ with any framing and $m=m_0$ is its meridian with $-1$ framing. Suppose $m_1,\dots,m_{p-1}$ are unknots with framings $-2$, such that $m_{i-1}$ and $m_i$ are linked as a Hopf link for $i=1,\dots,p-1$. See the left picture for $p=3$. Let $X$ be the 4-manifold obtained by attaching 2-handles along $K,m_0,\dots,m_{p-1}$ with given framings. For $i=1,\dots,p-1$, let $S_i$ be the sphere obtained by capping the core of the 2-handle along $m_i$. Let $Y=N(\cup_{i=1}^{p-1}S_i)$ be the neighborhood (see the red part of the left figure). It can be shown by Kirby calculus that $\partial Y$ is the lens space $L(p,-p+1)\cong L(p,1)$, where we assume $L(p,1)$ is obtained by $+p$ surgery on the unknot. Let $Z$ be obtained by attaching 2-handle along an unknot with framing $+p$. Then $\partial Z=L(p,1)$.

What's the Kirby diagram of $(X-Y)\cup Z$? I guess it is the right figure below (the $+3$ framing should be $+p$ framing in general). But I'm not sure about the framing of the meridian $m$. Is it $0$ or still $-1$?

[image]

Comment: It's 0; you can check that it can't be 1 by a determinant computation, for instance in the case when there is no K. (The determinant computes H_1 of the boundary. In this case you can even pin down the manifold.)